# Change direction depending from where you are coming in a Sencha Touch app

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have an application created with Sencha Touch, in the header of the app I have a segmented-button with three different options, when I change among views and I am working with this code:

```
this.getEditorGeneral().animateActiveItem(0, {type:'slide', direction: 'right'});
```

(I change number for each button in the segmented-button, this example is only for the first choice)

Question is how to define animation depending if I am changing from the third option to the second option and from the second option to the third option for instance, my idea is change the direction..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can listen to [activeitemchange](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.SegmentedButton-event-activeitemchange) event, its handler function takes as arguments both newValue and Oldvalue - `function( this, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ) {}`.

Ehm, Im not sure about your app structure, but idea is that you have to lister for `segmentedbutton` event `activeitemchange` (in Controller, with using of `.on()` or any other way you prefer) and do something like:

```
myButton.on(
    'activeitemchange',
    function( segmentedbutton, newValue, oldValue ) {
        // from second button to third, idk you actual button values so its just 2 and 3
        if( newValue === 3 && oldValue === 2) {
            this.getEditorGeneral().animateActiveItem(0, {type:'slide', direction: 'right'});
        // and vice versa
        } else if( newValue === 2 && oldValue === 3) {
            this.getEditorGeneral().animateActiveItem(0, {type:'slide', direction: 'left'});
        }
    },
    // make sure that you pass proper scope so you can use getEditorGeneral()
    this
);
```

Comment: Added example to illustrate what I mean, sorry if I missunderstand your question in touch-specific part, Im actually ExtJS developer, not touch.

Comment: I suppose myButton would be a reference to my segmented button, right?

Comment: Currently I have implemented for each segmentedButton pressed one method with the code previously specified in the post, could I implement your example of different way but with my current code?

Comment: As I understand at the moment you have separate handler for each of your segmentedButton? If you would not add single `activeitemchange`  event listener for segmentedButton, you can save currently selected button value in any place in your code and on button click handler compare this value with clicked button value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set different objects animations, maybe you can try to use a switch case to set the direction string before setting the animation.

```
var direction='yourDirection',
anim={type:'slide', direction: direction};
this.getEditorGeneral().animateActiveItem(0, anim);
```

maybe i can't understand your request